# Why are files and directories colored in different ways?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ls, colors, gnome-terminal

On Ubuntu 14.04, in bash under gnome terminal, Why are files especially directories colored  in different ways?

[image]

The green colors hide the text to me (How about to you?). Is it done by terminal or bash? Is it a design  for some purpose?

Can we change the color that hide the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colours are set by `ls`, using the `LS_COLORS` environment variable. To change the colours, you can use `dircolors`.

```
dircolors --print-database
```

outputs the current source settings, which you can store in a file and adapt; then

```
dircolors ${file}
```

will output the processed `LS_COLORS` value for you using the settings in `${file}`.

Strictly speaking `ls` outputs colour codes, and these are mapped to colours by the terminal; there's a more-or-less standard palette (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) for details) but there are slight differences from one terminal to another. So you can change the codes `ls` outputs using `dircolors`, and you can often adjust the terminal's palette as well, but that would affect all colour-using programs you'd run in the terminal.

As to the design, I suppose the default colours are those the `ls` maintainers like...